# Pyinstaller missing modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have tried everything I've seen online and cannot figure out why this isn't working. I would be happy to provide any information you need but for the post itself, I don't want to post everything as some of it is probably unnecessary. Here is the warn.txt

```
This file lists modules PyInstaller was not able to find. This does not
necessarily mean this module is required for running you program. Python and
Python 3rd-party packages include a lot of conditional or optional modules. For
example the module 'ntpath' only exists on Windows, whereas the module
'posixpath' only exists on Posix systems.

Types if import:
* top-level: imported at the top-level - look at these first
* conditional: imported within an if-statement
* delayed: imported from within a function
* optional: imported within a try-except-statement

IMPORTANT: Do NOT post this list to the issue-tracker. Use it as a basis for
           yourself tracking down the missing module. Thanks!

missing module named _posixsubprocess - imported by multiprocessing.util (delayed), subprocess (optional)
missing module named grp - imported by shutil (optional), tarfile (optional), pathlib (delayed, optional), subprocess (optional), distutils.archive_util (optional), py._path.local (delayed), pathlib2 (delayed), gevent.subprocess (optional)
missing module named pwd - imported by posixpath (delayed, conditional), shutil (optional), tarfile (optional), pathlib (delayed, conditional, optional), http.server (delayed, optional), webbrowser (delayed), netrc (delayed, conditional), getpass (delayed), distutils.util (delayed, conditional, optional), subprocess (optional), distutils.archive_util (optional), psutil (optional), py._path.local (delayed), pathlib2 (delayed, conditional, optional), docutils.frontend (delayed, conditional, optional), gevent.subprocess (optional)
missing module named _posixshmem - imported by multiprocessing.resource_tracker (conditional), multiprocessing.shared_memory (conditional)
missing module named multiprocessing.set_start_method - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.spawn (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.get_start_method - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.spawn (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.get_context - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.pool (top-level), multiprocessing.managers (top-level), multiprocessing.sharedctypes (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.TimeoutError - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.pool (top-level)
missing module named fcntl - imported by atomicwrites (optional), pty (delayed, optional), ptyprocess.ptyprocess (top-level), psutil._compat (delayed, optional), py._io.terminalwriter (delayed, conditional), xmlrpc.server (optional), paramiko.agent (delayed), zmq.eventloop.minitornado.platform.posix (top-level), sphinx.util.console (delayed, optional), gevent.fileobject (optional), gevent.os (optional), gevent.subprocess (conditional)
missing module named urllib.url2pathname - imported by urllib (conditional), docutils.writers._html_base (conditional), docutils.writers.latex2e (conditional), docutils.parsers.rst.directives.images (conditional)
missing module named urllib.urlretrieve - imported by urllib (conditional, optional), pygments.lexers._php_builtins (conditional, optional)
missing module named urllib.FancyURLopener - imported by urllib (conditional, optional), pygments.lexers._sourcemod_builtins (conditional, optional)
missing module named urllib.urlopen - imported by urllib (conditional, optional), pygments.lexers._postgres_builtins (conditional, optional), pygments.lexers._lua_builtins (conditional, optional), lxml.html (delayed, optional)
missing module named urllib.getproxies_environment - imported by urllib (conditional), requests.compat (conditional)
missing module named urllib.proxy_bypass_environment - imported by urllib (conditional), requests.compat (conditional)
missing module named urllib.proxy_bypass - imported by urllib (conditional), requests.compat (conditional)
missing module named urllib.getproxies - imported by urllib (conditional), requests.compat (conditional)
missing module named urllib.unquote_plus - imported by urllib (conditional), requests.compat (conditional)
missing module named urllib.quote_plus - imported by urllib (conditional), requests.compat (conditional), docutils.utils.math.math2html (conditional), prometheus_client.exposition (optional)
missing module named urllib.unquote - imported by urllib (conditional), jsonschema.compat (conditional), requests.compat (conditional), gevent.pywsgi (optional)
missing module named urllib.pathname2url - imported by urllib (conditional), jsonschema.compat (conditional)
missing module named urllib.urlencode - imported by urllib (delayed, conditional, optional), IPython.lib.display (delayed, conditional, optional), requests.compat (conditional), lxml.html (delayed, optional)
missing module named urllib.quote - imported by urllib (optional), jinja2._compat (optional), py._path.svnwc (delayed), pathlib2 (optional), requests.compat (conditional)
missing module named termios - imported by tty (top-level), getpass (optional), ptyprocess.ptyprocess (top-level), psutil._compat (delayed, optional), py._io.terminalwriter (delayed, conditional), prompt_toolkit.input.vt100 (top-level), sphinx.util.console (delayed, optional), click._termui_impl (conditional), IPython.core.page (delayed, optional)
missing module named vms_lib - imported by platform (delayed, optional)
missing module named 'java.lang' - imported by platform (delayed, optional), xml.sax._exceptions (conditional)
missing module named java - imported by platform (delayed)
missing module named _winreg - imported by platform (delayed, optional), pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs (delayed, conditional), requests.utils (delayed, conditional, optional), nbconvert.preprocessors.svg2pdf (conditional, optional), babel.localtime._win32 (optional), appdirs (delayed, conditional), pygments.formatters.img (optional)
missing module named _scproxy - imported by urllib.request (conditional)
missing module named 'org.python' - imported by copy (optional), setuptools.sandbox (conditional), xml.sax (delayed, conditional)
missing module named multiprocessing.BufferTooShort - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.connection (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.AuthenticationError - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.connection (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.cpu_count - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), gevent.testing.testrunner (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.freeze_support - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), black (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.Process - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), jupyter_client.ssh.tunnel (top-level), gevent.tests.test__issue600 (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.Manager - imported by multiprocessing (optional), nose.plugins.plugintest (optional), black (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.current_process - imported by multiprocessing (delayed), nose.plugins.plugintest (delayed)
missing module named asyncio.DefaultEventLoopPolicy - imported by asyncio (delayed, conditional), asyncio.events (delayed, conditional)
missing module named console - imported by pyreadline.console.ansi (conditional)
missing module named startup - imported by pyreadline.keysyms.common (conditional), pyreadline.keysyms.keysyms (conditional)
missing module named sets - imported by pyreadline.keysyms.common (optional), nose.util (optional), pytz.tzinfo (optional), jinja2.sandbox (optional)
missing module named System - imported by pyreadline.clipboard.ironpython_clipboard (top-level), pyreadline.keysyms.ironpython_keysyms (top-level), pyreadline.console.ironpython_console (top-level), pyreadline.rlmain (conditional), IPython.utils._process_cli (top-level)
missing module named StringIO - imported by pyreadline.py3k_compat (conditional), py._io.capture (optional), six (conditional), urllib3.packages.six (conditional), requests.compat (conditional), babel._compat (conditional), docutils.writers.docutils_xml (conditional), docutils.writers.odf_odt (conditional)
missing module named IronPythonConsole - imported by pyreadline.console.ironpython_console (top-level)
missing module named clr - imported by pyreadline.clipboard.ironpython_clipboard (top-level), pyreadline.console.ironpython_console (top-level), nose.suite (conditional), IPython.utils._process_cli (top-level)
missing module named org - imported by pickle (optional)
missing module named _frozen_importlib_external - imported by importlib._bootstrap (delayed), importlib (optional), importlib.abc (optional), zipimport (top-level)
excluded module named _frozen_importlib - imported by importlib (optional), importlib.abc (optional), zipimport (top-level)
missing module named pep517 - imported by importlib.metadata (delayed), importlib_metadata (delayed)
missing module named posix - imported by os (conditional, optional), shutil (conditional), importlib._bootstrap_external (conditional)
missing module named resource - imported by posix (top-level), test.support (delayed, conditional, optional), ptyprocess.ptyprocess (top-level), psutil._pslinux (optional), IPython.utils.timing (optional), prometheus_client.process_collector (optional)
missing module named pyimod03_importers - imported by C:\Users\reidw\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_pkgutil.py (top-level)
missing module named numpy.testing.knownfailureif - imported by numpy.testing (optional), IPython.external.decorators (optional)
missing module named numpy.testing.KnownFailure - imported by numpy.testing (optional), IPython.external.decorators (optional)
missing module named psutil._psutil_aix - imported by psutil (top-level), psutil._psaix (top-level)
missing module named psutil._psutil_sunos - imported by psutil (top-level), psutil._pssunos (top-level)
missing module named psutil._psutil_bsd - imported by psutil (top-level), psutil._psbsd (top-level)
missing module named psutil._psutil_osx - imported by psutil (top-level), psutil._psosx (top-level)
missing module named psutil._psutil_linux - imported by psutil (top-level), psutil._pslinux (top-level)
missing module named dummy_threading - imported by psutil._compat (optional), requests.cookies (optional), matplotlib.pyplot (optional), matplotlib.font_manager (optional), matplotlib.backends.backend_agg (optional)
missing module named _curses - imported by curses (top-level), curses.has_key (top-level)
missing module named _dummy_thread - imported by cffi.lock (conditional, optional), numpy.core.arrayprint (optional)
missing module named numpy.core.result_type - imported by numpy.core (delayed), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.float_ - imported by numpy.core (delayed), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.number - imported by numpy.core (delayed), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.object_ - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.all - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.bool_ - imported by numpy.core (delayed), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.inf - imported by numpy.core (delayed), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.array2string - imported by numpy.core (delayed), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.signbit - imported by numpy.core (delayed), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.isscalar - imported by numpy.core (delayed), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed), numpy.lib.polynomial (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.isinf - imported by numpy.core (delayed), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.errstate - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.isfinite - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.isnan - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.array - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (top-level), numpy.lib.polynomial (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.isnat - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.ndarray - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (top-level), numpy.lib.utils (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.array_repr - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.arange - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (top-level), numpy.fft.helper (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.empty - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (top-level), numpy.fft.helper (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.float32 - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.intp - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.linspace - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.lib.index_tricks (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.iinfo - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.lib.twodim_base (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.transpose - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.lib.function_base (top-level)
missing module named numpy.random.randn - imported by numpy.random (top-level), scipy (top-level)
missing module named numpy.random.rand - imported by numpy.random (top-level), scipy (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.roll - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.fft.helper (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.asarray - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.fft._pocketfft (top-level), numpy.fft.helper (top-level), numpy.lib.utils (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.integer - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.fft.helper (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.sqrt - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.fft._pocketfft (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.take - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.fft._pocketfft (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.conjugate - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.fft._pocketfft (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.swapaxes - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.fft._pocketfft (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.zeros - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.fft._pocketfft (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.sort - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.argsort - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.sign - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.count_nonzero - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.divide - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.matmul - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.asanyarray - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.atleast_2d - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.product - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.amax - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.amin - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.moveaxis - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.geterrobj - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.finfo - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.lib.polynomial (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.sum - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.fastCopyAndTranspose - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.multiply - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.add - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.dot - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.lib.polynomial (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.Inf - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.newaxis - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.complexfloating - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.inexact - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.cdouble - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.csingle - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.double - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.single - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.intc - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.empty_like - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.ufunc - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.lib.utils (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.ones - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.lib.polynomial (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.hstack - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.lib.polynomial (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.atleast_1d - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.lib.polynomial (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.atleast_3d - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.lib.shape_base (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.vstack - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.lib.shape_base (top-level)
missing module named pickle5 - imported by numpy.compat.py3k (optional), cloudpickle.compat (conditional, optional)
missing module named numpy.eye - imported by numpy (delayed), numpy.core.numeric (delayed)
missing module named numpy.recarray - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.mrecords (top-level)
missing module named numpy.dtype - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.mrecords (top-level), numpy.ctypeslib (top-level)
missing module named numpy.expand_dims - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.core (top-level)
missing module named numpy.array - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.core (top-level), numpy.ma.extras (top-level), numpy.ma.mrecords (top-level)
missing module named numpy.bool_ - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.core (top-level), numpy.ma.mrecords (top-level)
missing module named numpy.iscomplexobj - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.core (top-level)
missing module named numpy.amin - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.core (top-level)
missing module named numpy.amax - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.core (top-level)
missing module named numpy.ndarray - imported by numpy (conditional), _pytest.python_api (conditional), numpy.ma.core (top-level), numpy.ma.extras (top-level), numpy.ma.mrecords (top-level), numpy.ctypeslib (top-level), IPython.core.magics.namespace (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named numpy.histogramdd - imported by numpy (delayed), numpy.lib.twodim_base (delayed)
```

here is my code:

```
import sys

import cv2
import numpy as np
from tkinter import Tk     # from tkinter import Tk for Python 3.x
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename

# Grayscale Image
def processImage(image):
    image = cv2.imread(image)
    image = cv2.cvtColor(src=image, code=cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    return image


def convolve2D(image, kernel, padding=0, strides=1):
    # Cross Correlation
    kernel = np.flipud(np.fliplr(kernel))

    # Gather Shapes of Kernel + Image + Padding
    xKernShape = kernel.shape[0]
    yKernShape = kernel.shape[1]
    xImgShape = image.shape[0]
    yImgShape = image.shape[0]

    # Shape of Output Convolution
    xOutput = int(((xImgShape - xKernShape + 2 * padding) / strides) + 1)
    yOutput = int(((yImgShape - yKernShape + 2 * padding) / strides) + 1)
    output = np.zeros((xOutput, yOutput))

    # Apply Equal Padding to All Sides
    if padding != 0:
        imagePadded = np.zeros((image.shape[0] + padding*2, image.shape[1] + padding*2))
        imagePadded[int(padding):int(-1 * padding), int(padding):int(-1 * padding)] = image
    else:
        imagePadded = image

    # Iterate through image
    for y in range(image.shape[1]):
        # Exit Convolution
        if y > image.shape[1] - yKernShape:
            break
        # Only Convolve if y has gone down by the specified Strides
        if y % strides == 0:
            for x in range(image.shape[0]):
                # Go to next row once kernel is out of bounds
                if x > image.shape[0] - xKernShape:
                    break
                try:
                    # Only Convolve if x has moved by the specified Strides
                    if x % strides == 0:
                        output[x, y] = (kernel * imagePadded[x: x + xKernShape, y: y + yKernShape]).sum()
                except:
                    break

    return output


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Ask user for input image
    print('Please choose the image you would like to use')
    print('Keep in mind that if the image is not already square, it will convert the image into a square')
    Tk().withdraw() # we don't want a full GUI, so keep the root window from appearing
    uploadedImage = askopenfilename() # show an "Open" dialog box and return the path to the selected file
    
    #Ask user for output path
    print('Please choose the folder you would like the output image to go into')
    Tk().withdraw() # we don't want a full GUI, so keep the root window from appearing
    outputDirectory = asksaveasfilename() # show an "Open" dialog box and return the path to the selected file

    # Grayscale Image
    image = processImage(uploadedImage)

    # Edge Detection Kernel
    kernel = np.array([[-1, -1, -1], [-1, 8, -1], [-1, -1, -1]])

    # Convolve and Save Output
    output = convolve2D(image, kernel, padding=0)
    cv2.imwrite(outputDirectory + '.jpg', output)
```

Any help is appreciated! Sorry, I'm very new to this and don't know what's helpful and not.

Comment: What “isn’t working”? Be specific. What’s the actual error message you get - edit the __full__ message into your question as text. Also are you using the latest version of PyInstaller?

Comment: I used --windowed to see what was happening because the exe instantly closed. I am assuming it's because of alll of the missing modules, here is the output from the exe.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "algorithm.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
  File "cv2\__init__.py", line 188, in <module>
  File "cv2\__init__.py", line 118, in bootstrap
  File "cv2\__init__.py", line 116, in load_first_config
ImportError: OpenCV loader: missing configuration file: ['config.py']. Check OpenCV installation.

Comment: `Python` wasn't created to build .exe files and priograms like `PyInstaller` may have problem to find all needed Python modules and C/C++ libraries - but you can use special file `.spec` to add manually missed modules and libraries. Check PyInstaller documentation: [Adding Files to the Bundle](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-files-to-the-bundle)

Answer (score 0):

I can understand your struggle with Pyinstaller but no need to worry whenever you execute pyinstaller command to create exe build it gives errors about missing modules. You can use hidden import flag **--hidden-import=modulename** to include whatever package is showing as missing one by one as below:

pyinstaller <yourfile.py> --hidden-import=missingmodulename1 --hidden-import=missingmodule2